# Render a View after an AJAX call in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to load a view after an ajax call. After the ajax call my action method will return a `view` which is going to be loaded after the call is success.

AJAX I'm using

> > function PostMethods(url, fname, lname, email) {
> >
> > ```
> > var userRegisterViewModel = {
> >     FirstName: fname,
> >     LastName: lname,
> >     Email: email
> > };
> > $.ajax({
> >     type: 'Post',
> >     dataType: "json",
> >     url: url,
> >     contentType: 'application/json',
> >     data: JSON.stringify(userRegisterViewModel),
> > ```
> >
> > //Success and error code
> >
> > ```
> > });}
> > ```

My ajax calling an api method where I'm passing `fname`, `lname` and `email`. Now my api method successfully stores those data to database it will return a `View` if fails to store data it will return an error message which I can show to user in current view. In the HTML of the current view has an empty `<spam>` to show the error message.

My Action Method is:

```
    public ActionResult RegisterAndLogin(UserRegisterViewModel model)
    {
        ActionResult returnNextPage = null;
        bool successToStoreData = SomeMethod(model);
        if (successToStoreData)
        {
            returnNextPage = RedirectToAction(string.Empty, "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            //Text message to show to the user
        }
        return returnNextPage;
    }
```

What code I should write to do this in AXAJ and action method

Comment: AJAX calls stay on the same page so `RedirectToAction` does not work. Do you want to render the view on same page or do you want to redirect to another page if there are no errors?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to redirect to another page. But if and only if Data saves successfully.

Comment: Then why not use a standard form with submit which allows you do do a redirect? If the data did not save correctly, then just return the view and display any validation errors.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I wanted to use that but my html is not much reliable for that. Example: In my Log in page has a button call register now clicking this a div become visible and cover all the page area. If I reload the page I can only see the register button not the div

Comment: Well that a separate issue and perhaps you should post a separate question to help solve it but I'll post an answer for this one, although I don't believe its the correct approach

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeh, Please I'll try

Comment: return url as string and redirect via javascript to that url

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AJAX calls stay on the same page so RedirectToAction does not work. You need to modify your controller to return JSON, for example

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RegisterAndLogin(UserRegisterViewModel model)
{
  bool successToStoreData = SomeMethod(model);
  if (successToStoreData)
  {
    return null; // indicates success
  }
  else
  {
    return Json("Your error message");
  }
}
```

and modify the AJAX function

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'Post',
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify(userRegisterViewModel),
  success: function(message) {
    if (message) {
      $('yourSpanSelector').text(message); // display the error message in the span tag
    } else {
      window.location.href='/YourController/YourAction' // redirect to another page
    }
  }
})
```