# How to return the view of a controller that is protected with Authorize (JWT)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, bearer-token

I am working with ASP.NET Core MVC and JWT. After getting the token from localstorage and making a request to a controller that is protected with `[Authorize]` and manages to enter and validate the token, it does not open the index of that controller - it does not redirect it to that controller's page. The result I get is the HTML script and then Unauthorized 401. How can this be solved?

This is my JavasSript code:

```js
var apiUrl = "http://localhost:61545/User/Index";
$("#btntest").click(function () 
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: apiUrl,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"));
        },
        success: function () {
            alert("enter")
            window.open("/User/Index");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('wrong!');
        }
    })
})
```

Here's the controller:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a number of things that could be wrong here. The first thing to check is that your authentication services and/or authentication middleware are configured correctly. You might want to include your `Startup`'s `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` functions in the question.

Comment: In startup, I have added the functions of ConfigureServices, the reason for the question is that
I can't return the index view of the controller, since every time it enter the controller returns
to the ajax part and does not display the view. could you help me?
I found these options but it did not work   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994897/render-a-view-after-an-ajax-call-in-asp-net-mvc     and     https://github.com/auth0-samples/aspnet-core-mvc-plus-webapi/blob/master/SampleMvcApp/Controllers/AccountController.cs

Comment: Yes, I want to help but it's difficult to know where your problem lies. You might want to consider creating a [mcve] for this.